# Cannot get Fabric8 to fully launch in AWS using stackpoint

Tags: fabric8

I have been trying to spin up a Kubernetes/Fabric8 installation on AWS using Stackpoint as described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNRpGJTSMKA

My problem is that three of the apps wont start becuase no volumes are available and I cannot see how to resolve those PV requests. For example Gogs is reporting the following error:

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "gogs-2568819805-bcw8e_default(03d618b9-7477-11e6-8c6b-0a945216fb91)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "gogs-2568819805-bcw8e"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[gogs-data]
Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "gogs-2568819805-bcw8e"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[gogs-data]
```

I am pretty sure this is very simple but cannot see how to connect the dots here from the various K8, Fabric8 docs. I can create a new EBS volume in AWS easily enough but cannot see how to then update this running stack to attach it to these services. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, what version of gofabric8 are you using?  We're currently adding persistent volume support for the core platform apps although the integration our stackpoint isn't there quite yet.  Hopefully soon though.

For now you should be able to disable the PV claims using `--pv=false` during the deploy.  So `gofabric8 deploy --pv=false`.  We'll look at using this as the default until the integration is there and we can leverage AWS persistent volumes

Comment: I was using 0.4.45 but just pulled the latest. This allowed me to get the pods started except Gogs which is failing to launch with "Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "gogs" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=gogs pod=gogs-2568819805-hxlyi_default(1a540c2b-7b4b-11e6-8c6b-0a945216fb91)""

Comment: I added a separate issue for this on github as it seems to be a problem pulling fabric8/gogs from dockerhub. https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/6352.

Answer (score 0):

We just shipped functionality that allows you to create and manage AWS volumes for Kubernetes. You get a volume, PV, and claim - just name the claim to be what is required by Fabric8. Eventually, you'll be able to use dynamic volume creation.